# State number of partial order relations $U$ on $\{a,b,c,d\}$ such that $bUa,cUa,dUa$ and some other conditions.

Tags: relations, order-theory

$\require{cancel}$

> State how many possible partial order relations $U$ are there on the set $\{a,b,c,d\}$ such that
>
> - $bUa, cUa, dUa;$ and
> - $b\cancel U c, c\cancel U b, d\cancel U b \text{ and } b\cancel U c$.

How should I tackle this question?

> A relation is Partial Order relation if it is Reflexive, Anti-Symmetric and Transitive

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I think it is enough to find the (number of) partial orders on $\{b,c,d\}$.

Comment: @drhab what do you mean by that ?

Comment: It is only meant for the first bullet (when I commented there was only one problem). A partial order on $b,c,d$ extended with the 3 mentioned relations gives a partial order on $a,b,c,d$. Conversely *every* partial order on $a,b,c,d$ characterized by the 3 relations can be build up like that.

Comment: @drhab I apologize for the mistake, when I looked back at the question that I posted I only realize that I left out one part of the question. So the thing I needed to do for this question is that try to find out how many partial order relation can I get from the first bullet point ?

Comment: When I read your question now I see two interpretations. 1) It is *one* question and you must find the number of partial orders on $a,b,c,d$ such that the conditions mentioned under *both* bullets are satisfied. 2) two separate questions. The first is linked with the first bullet and the second with the second bullet. What is the correct interpretation?

Comment: @drhab This question is very confusing for me cause I've no idea where to start, that's why I came here to ask for some guidance on this question.

Comment: Are you capable to find how many partial orders exist on - let's say - a set having 2 (or 3) elements?

Comment: @drhab not really T.T

Comment: On singleton $\{a\}$ there is exactly one which is $\{(a,a)\}$. On $\{a,b\}$ there are 3. Each of them contain the elements $(a,a)$ and $(b,b)$ because there is reflexivity and $\{(a,a),(b,b)\}$ is one of them. It can be extended with $(a,b)$ or $(b,a)$ (not both) giving the other two. Now give it a try for $\{a,b,c\}$. In principle you can investigate on every relation and check on reflexivity, transitivity and anti-symmetry. There are $2^9$ relations though so the art is to exclude lots of them asap. For instance they *must* be reflexive. Good luck.

Comment: @drhab Noted, i appreciate your help. Thank you